# How to use my own audio play control button in HTML5?

Tags: html5-audio

I am just now being exposed to the HTML5 audio feature, so thanks in advance for bearing with me.

What I would like to do is to have my graphic object act as a play button instead of putting up the standard controls. I'm afraid my javascript is weak (working on it). Can anyone give me a hand on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see that I redceived a down vote on this question. This is my first post to stackoverflow and I tried to look through existing questions but could not find a match to my needs. If this question is not clear or not useful, please tell me how to improve on it. Sometimes newbies can use a helping hand. Isn't this why we're here?

Comment: I think the reason you got a down vote (I didn't downvote myself) was because questions that are too broad or "please write code for me" aren't allowed. I'll go ahead and give you some pointers though!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the section called **Controlling media playback** here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

That'll show you how to grab your element from the page and programmatically start it (the audio and video elements are interchangeable in this case). What you then need to do is to get your button (in the same fashion) and attach a click event listener (google addEventListener) and from within the listener start your element.